# how to paste different column names in particular rows in single column excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How to paste different column names in particular rows in excel through Macro.

For Example :

I am having 10 different columns each column has 10 rows of data.

i have done coding for pasting those 10 column values in a single column (ex : A Column) (Hence 100 rows of data -> 10 rows *10 columns) but i need to paste all those 10 column names in B column in rows corresponding to the column values.

Before My Coding :

```
Name 1  Name 2  Name 3  Name 4
A       E       H       K
B       F       I       L
C       G       J       M
```

After My Coding :

```
Name 1  Name 2  Name 3  Name 4
A           
B           
C           
E           
F           
G           
H           
I           
J           
K           
L           
M
```

What I am expecting now !!

```
Name    Name Category
A       Name 1
B       Name 1
C       Name 1
E       Name 2
F       Name 2
G       Name 2
H       Name 3
I       Name 3
J       Name 3
K       Name 4
L       Name 4
M       Name 4
```

Any excel expert please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Once you've moved them all to column A you kind of loose the connection unless you have designed a struct/own datatype for each obj to store both the letter and name. Show your current code so we can help you modify it

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've tested the following code on your example table and it seems to be working.

```
Sub VijayRamRaja()
Dim cols As Integer
cols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For iCol = 2 To cols
    Dim tHead, tData, tNewS
    Set tHead = Cells(1, iCol)
    Set tData = Range(Cells(2, iCol), tHead.End(xlDown))
    tNewS = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Address

    tData.Cut Range(tNewS)

    For Each iCell In Range(Range(tNewS), Range(tNewS).End(xlDown))
        iCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = tHead.Value2
    Next iCell

    tHead.Clear
Next iCol

For Each iCell In Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0))
    iCell.Value2 = Range("A1").Value2
Next iCell

ActiveSheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```